# Why onChange result is "false" in test LiveData

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, androidx, mutablelivedata

It's first my post on stackoverflow and i'm beginer in kotlin, Lifecycle, need help with it. I lost 2 days with it and need help.

I have SplashViewModel class

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val configuration: IConfiguration,
    private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable) : BaseViewModel(compositeDisposable), SplashContract.ViewModel{

override val isLoggedLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    setLoginStatus()
}

override fun setLoginStatus(){
    isLoggedLiveData.postValue(configuration.isUserLoggedIn())
}}
```

SplashViewModelTest class

```
class SplashViewModelTest : BaseTest(){

@get:Rule
val testRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Mock
private lateinit var configuration: IConfiguration

@Mock
private lateinit var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable

@Mock
private lateinit var observer: Observer<Boolean>

private lateinit var viewModel: SplashContract.ViewModel

override fun setup() {
    super.setup()
    trampolineRxPlugin()
    viewModel = SplashViewModel(
            configuration,
            compositeDisposable
    )
}

override fun tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(
            configuration,
            compositeDisposable
    )
}

@Test
fun `should change livedata status to true when viewmodel is initialize`() {
    val isLogged = true

    `when`(configuration.isUserLoggedIn()).thenReturn(isLogged)

    viewModel.isLoggedLiveData.observeForever(observer)

    verify(configuration, Mockito.times(1)).isUserLoggedIn()
    verify(observer).onChanged(isLogged)
}
```

When run this test result is error

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
observer.onChanged(true);
-> at com.example.kotlinmvvm.feature.splash.viewModel.SplashViewModelTest.should check configuration user login status when getIsLoggedLiveData is called(SplashViewModelTest.kt:85)

Actual invocation has different arguments:
observer.onChanged(false);
-> at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)

Comparison Failure:

Expected :observer.onChanged(true);

Actual   :observer.onChanged(false);

Who knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suspect is happening is that you're instantiating view model (in `setup`) prior to following being invoked (with `isLogged` = `true`)...which is causing code in `init` to be invoked...and at that point it will return false.

```
`when`(configuration.isUserLoggedIn()).thenReturn(isLogged)
```

Did you intend perhaps to explicitly call `setLoginStatus` in your test as well (after above line)?

Comment: When I add 
`viewModel.setLoginStatus()`
and change 
`verify(configuration, times(2)).isUserLoggedIn()`
 then onChange return true and test is pass

But is it correct way to make test it ? 
Sorry but these are my first tests :)

Comment: In that case you have invoked it twice - once in the `init` block and again when you invoked it in test.  Judging from title of test (which I missed when answering iniitally) you're specifically testing that `setLoginStatus` is invoked in `init` block....in that case I'd call ` `when`(configuration.isUserLoggedIn()).thenReturn(isLogged)` before you instantiate the view model